# ST2: how do I rebind the key for viewing a function list?

Tags: sublimetext

I've switched from emacs to Sublime Text 2. In order to move around files quickly, I've installed emacs keybindings.

Now I would like to get an overview of the code in a file. Googling, I can see that there is a function for doing this, normally accessible by hitting 'Ctrl+r'.

This key is now bound to an emacs-style search function.

Searching again, I can see that I can create a new keybinding by editing a file called .sublime-keymap.

I can't find this file in my system.

Where should I expect to find this file?

Answer (score 0):

The preferences menu of the app gives you a link to opening the settings and keymaps.

Physically, it lives in the platform specific Sublime Packages location -> Packages -> User